# Exporting Data Or Code To A .png

Tags: vb.net

How Do you Export Code To A .png In Order To Make It Animated?
I Am Using VB.Net 2008 Express Edition.

Comment: You want to export the code to a png? An image of your source code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a page like "myimage.aspx" and in the codebehind (sorry, this is C#)

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
```

Use the gfx to draw on the image (see it's methods).
Then return the PNG in the response stream

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
Response.BinaryWrite(ms.GetBuffer());
Response.End();
```

You can then reference this in HTML like

```
<img src="myimage.aspx" />
```